# Check if a user, any user, not current user, is logged In

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

I want to check if a user, any user, is logged in, in order to send a push to him only if the user is logged in. How can I do this with PFQuery?

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far to do this?

Comment: what will be sending this push? do you have explicit logout?

Comment: I do not want send a push to a not logged user. PFQuery asks fields but no field corresponds to a flag for login values yes / no, maybe I need to add it and manage by code?

Comment: @WaiHaLee thanks for corrections, sorry but my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "connected" field in Users database.

When the user is logged in, you set this field to TRUE and when he is logged out, you set this field to FALSE.

And before to send your push, you check if the "connected" field is TRUE.

It's a solution.